# QT4 porting on Freescale i.MX6 SABRE LITE board

Tags: qt4, arm, cross-compiling, embedded-linux

- I want to run a QT Gui application on an [iMX6 SABRE LITE](http://boundarydevices.com/products/sabre-lite-imx6-sbc/) board.
- For that I need to cross compile *qt-everywhere-opensource-src-4.6.2* using `arm-linux-gnueabi` compiler.
- I am using [treyweaver.blogspot.in](http://treyweaver.blogspot.in/2010/10/setting-up-qt-development-environment.html) as a reference, which describes porting QT on a beagle board.
- Can anyone tell me if it is possible to port QT using this link as reference? If it is so what configuration do I need to change?

Comment: Yes, this is how general flow shall look. When you adjust tutorial to your compiler then shall work. You can also take a look on:

1. [other stackoverflow question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31811237/how-do-i-cross-compile-a-qt-application-for-imx6)
2.[tutorial on freescale page](https://community.freescale.com/docs/DOC-94066)