# How do I cross-compile a QT application for imx6?

Tags: linux, qt, arm, cross-compiling

How do I cross-compile a QT application for a Freescale Hummingboard(imx6(arm))?

There are some guides around, but I've not been able to complete one with success.

The following (and more) guides give me a compile error on ./configure
http://forum.solid-run.com/linux-on-cubox-i-and-hummingboard-f8/qt5-3-on-hummingboard-t2072.html
https://community.freescale.com/docs/DOC-94066
When I run the ./configure command (With recommended commands, I've tried this with a lot of possibilities for commands but got none working). I got a compile error for all the external libraries QT uses (zlib, libjpeg, libpng, etc.). So it's a dead end from there.

I've tried a lot more stuff, I don't even remember all the stuff I've tried, but I got nothing working.

I'm trying to use mini-distribution for the Hummingboard. It's a system without window manager that is able to run QT applications (QT5). The build tool I'm trying to use is gcc-linaro-arm-linux-gnueabi, I'm using QT Creator. I've got QT working on the Hummingboard, I just can't compile anything for it.

Comment: What are the actual errors? Can the cross-compiler definitely see the appropriate headers and (ARM versions of) libraries from the target filesystem? (Note: _not_ those of your host machine)

Comment: This is the output of the command:
http://pastebin.com/EW1Hwd5F

I run this command:
./configure \
-opengl es2 \
-device linux-imx6-g++ \
-device-option CROSS_COMPILE=/home/bob/Downloads/gcc-linaro-arm-linux-gnueabi-2012.04-20120426_linux/bin/arm-linux-gnueabi- \
-sysroot /media/bob/rootfs/ \
-opensource \
-confirm-license \
-optimized-qmake \
-release \
-make libs \
-prefix /opt/qtpls \
-no-pch \
-nomake examples \
-nomake tests \
-no-xcb \
-eglfs \
-v

Sysroot is set to the mounted image with the mini-distirbution

Comment: Read [some documentation](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/embedded-linux.html).  For Qt5, it seems you need a *-device* which specifies many things that are parameters in Qt4.  Your compiler error is on an *x86* file, which will not work with an ARM compiler.  Some things are host tools (cross-qmake), which do need a PC compiler.

Comment: Thanks for reply, as you can see I have device set to "-device linux-imx6-g++". I have the files which specify many things.

Comment: Do you have the headers required? You will have the libraries for sure because if you have built your rootfs with yocto you will not have the headers mostly unless you made some changes. Instead of using external libraries use qt libraries by passing these option  **(-qt-zlib -qt-libpng -qt-libjpeg)**

Answer (score 0):

I managed building an application for the IMX6 finally. Here is how I did it for other's. It's not an optimal solution but it is an solution.

I use Buildgear to build mini-distirbution as OS (Google it, not enough links with my reputation). I append my own application to this mini-distribution to also build it. This is done by placing creating a folder in the buildfiles/cross/cross-hummingboard folder and adding a buildfile (mine look like this http://pastebin.com/bZkJUiry). In this folder I also place a .tar of the project files (including the .pro). To get it to build I add "qt-gui" as a dependency to the fs (buildfiles/cross/cross-hummingboard/fs) by adding it to the list of depends.

I then run buildgear build fs, which will create an (Tarred) image including my (working) qt-application! I then extract the ./qt-gui executable and ssh it to the Hummingboard.

Of course this is all a bit cumbersome so I made a script that automates this all: http://pastebin.com/jFM6rZyY
It copies and Tars sources, compiles it together with the fs, extracts the executable, ssh's the file to the hummingboard and runs it. Takes about 3 minutes building but it works which is what counts for me at this point.